# How to filter rows based on comparison with values in other rows, in a grouped data frame in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame similar to the example below (which is a small section of my data frame). I would like to filter out rows based on the ‘pos’ column whereby I remove rows where the value is within 50 of one or more other rows, unless all of those nearby rows have values of less than 0.05 in either the ‘m_q_prop’ and ‘f_q_prop’ columns or ‘m_p_prop’ and ‘f_p_prop’ columns. In other words, remaining rows have a ‘pos’ value at least 50 away from other rows, or any rows within 50 of ‘pos’ have ‘m_q_prop’ and ‘f_p_prop’ or ‘m_p_prop’ and ‘f_p_prop’ values of less than 0.05. However, rows must be grouped by the ‘contig’ column, so that ‘pos’ values are only compared to other rows in the same ‘contig’ group.

I have attempted to use many various combinations of functions, such as those below, but all have produced errors. My assumption was that I would need to split the data frame by the ‘contig’ groups then filter the rows before rejoining the data frame. For the middle step, I tried to either directly filter the rows, or to create a new column of categories (e.g. suitable and unsuitable) that I could use to filter afterwards. The columns are also all characters so need to be converted to numeric, aside the ‘contig’ column (although the example data frame produces factors, and I am not sure how to convert those to characters to match my actual data).

Example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(contig=c("Contig101702", "Contig101702", "Contig103637", 
"Contig105622", "Contig105622", "Contig105622", "Contig105901", 
"Contig105901", "Contig117031", "Contig118816", "Contig120914", 
"Contig120914"), 
pos=c("12048", "13281", "1398", "1078", "1090", "1125", "7178", "7180", 
"3236", "3700", "56298", "56326"),
m_p_prop=c("0.9789", "0.9792", "0.9845", "0.9787", "0.9839", "0.9826", 
"0.9468", "0.9468", "0.9713", "0.9794", "0.0195", "0.0048"),
f_p_prop=c("0.5047", "0.5000", "0.5089", "0.5000", "0.5000", "0.5050", 
"0.4867", "0.4867", "0.4810", "0.5086", "0.0491", "0.0012"),
m_q_prop=c("0.0211", "0.0208", "0.0155", "0.0213", "0.0161", "0.01744", 
"0.0532", "0.0532", "0.0287", "0.0206", "0.9805", "0.0052"),
f_q_prop=c("0.495", "0.5000", "0.4911", "0.5000", "0.5000", "0.4950", 
"0.5133", "0.5133", "0.5190", "0.4914", "0.9509", "0.9988"))
```

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4CsE.png)

Expected output following filtering:

[df_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUh0q.png)

Examples of my attempts to filter (at this stage I was just attempting to filter by the 'pos' values, before I added the 'prop' requirements):

```
df_output <- df %>%
  split(df$contig) %>%
  by(function(x) {filter(!between(as.numeric(df$pos), 
                                 as.numeric(df$pos)-50, 
                                 as.numeric(df$pos)+50))}) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .)

df_output <- df %>%
  split(df$contig) %>%
  sapply( function(x) {filter(!as.numeric(df$pos)>=as.numeric(df$pos)-50 |
      !as.numeric(df$pos)<=as.numeric(df$pos)+50)}) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .)

df_output <- df %>% as.numeric(df$pos) %>%
  split(df$contig) %>%
  sapply( function(x)
   {mutate(suitable=ifelse(as.numeric(df$pos)>=as.numeric(df$pos)-50 |
                                            as.numeric(df$pos 
                                            <=as.numeric(df$pos)+50),
                              "bad", "good")}) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.)
```

Comment: could you give the desired output for your example ?

Comment: It is there already: it is the 'df_output' link to an image which is under the 'Expected output following filtering' heading

Comment: First, why you don't have numeric variables from the beginning? Second, be careful when you transform factor variables to numeric. Try `df$pos; as.numeric(df$pos)` using the dataset you posted and see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). First, I converted all your numbers to numeric.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(-contig), funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

After that, I created a list column called `Diff` with all the combinations of numbers in each `contig`. I then created a column called `Flag`, which is `TRUE` if all number pairs are larger than 50 or there is only one number. Finally, I merged the data frame back to the original data frame. i then filtered the data frame as `filter(Flag | (m_p_prop < 0.05 & f_p_prop < 0.05) | m_q_prop < 0.05 & f_q_prop < 0.05)`. `df2` is the final output.

If you don't want to use `map_lgl`, replace it with `sapply` would also work.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(contig) %>%
  summarise(Diff = ifelse(n() > 1, list(combn(pos, 2)), list(NA))) %>%
  mutate(Flag = map_lgl(Diff, function(x){
    if (is.null(dim(x))){
      return(TRUE)
    } else {
      return(all(abs(x[1, ] - x[2, ]) > 50))
    }
  })) %>%
  right_join(df, by = "contig") %>%
  filter(Flag | (m_p_prop < 0.05 & f_p_prop < 0.05) | (m_q_prop < 0.05 & f_q_prop < 0.05)) %>%
  select(-Diff, -Flag)

df2
# A tibble: 7 x 6
#   contig         pos m_p_prop f_p_prop m_q_prop f_q_prop
#   <fct>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 Contig101702 12048  0.979    0.505    0.0211     0.495
# 2 Contig101702 13281  0.979    0.500    0.0208     0.500
# 3 Contig103637  1398  0.984    0.509    0.0155     0.491
# 4 Contig117031  3236  0.971    0.481    0.0287     0.519
# 5 Contig118816  3700  0.979    0.509    0.0206     0.491
# 6 Contig120914 56298  0.0195   0.0491   0.980      0.951
# 7 Contig120914 56326  0.00480  0.00120  0.00520    0.999
```